# Oracle job sending email when dbms_job is broken

Tags: oracle, plsql, jobs, dbms-job

I m trying to crate notification to send email whenever job is broken. This is the job:

```
declare
   jobno number;
begin
   dbms_job.submit( jobno,
                   'test_job_procedure;',
                    SYSDATE,
                    'SYSDATE + 1/24 /12');
                    commit;
end;
```

This is configuration of credentials :

```
    BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_credential (credential_name   => 'MAILSERVER_CREDENTIAL',
    username          => 'test@gmail.com',
    password          => 'test');
    END;

    BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute ('email_server', 'smtp.gmail.com:587');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute ('email_sender', 'test@gmail.com');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute ('email_server_credential', 'MAILSERVER_CRED

ENTIAL');
END;
```

And this is email notification scheduler: Instead of what there was job_name but in dbms_job job names are numbers which are non consistent, when I restart the job it gets new number so I put WHAT as something that will recognize that job. I don't know if this could work because I am getting error at the end but anyway when i run this select

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_scheduler_global_attribute
```

I get this results https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFPcs.jpg

And this is job email notification :

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.ADD_JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION (
  what   =>  'test_job_procedure',
  recipients =>  'test1@gmail.com',
  sender     =>  'test@gmail.com',
  subject    =>  'Scheduler Job Notification',
  body       =>   '%event_type% occurred at %event_timestamp%. %error_message%',
  events     =>  'JOB_FAILED, JOB_BROKEN');
END;
```

can someone please go through this and tell me where am I making mistakes ?

Comment: "I am getting error at the end ".   OK, so what is the error?

Comment: ORA-00931: missing identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 167
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 4805
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 7595
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 4063

Comment: I guess dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('email_server_encryption','STARTTLS'); is necessary and you have to specify a wallet with google root certs in order to avoid ORA-29024 (certification validation error).